# D3 slider issue

Tags: d3.js

I have a line chart created using D3. X-axis is time scale and I have a slider(created using d3.drag) that can slide over the dates.

Issue is slider is moving out of the line chart.

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/kSLVraZT9YVKCgrPY5VP?p=preview

```
svg.append("rect")
  .style("pointer-events", "all")
  .style("fill", "none")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .style("cursor", "crosshair")
  .call(drag);
```

Can someone please have a look at the plunker and let me know how can we restrict slider movements out of the chart?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually check boundaries in updatePos function:

```
function updatePos(elem){
    var xPos = d3.mouse(  elem)[0];
    if (xPos > x(x.domain()[1])) {
      xPos = x(x.domain()[1])
    }
    if (xPos < x(x.domain()[0])) {
      xPos = x(x.domain()[0])
    }
    handle.attr('transform', 'translate(' + xPos + ",0)");
    sliderDateDisplay = formatDateSliderDisplay(x.invert(xPos));
    text.text(sliderDateDisplay);
}
```

Here is a demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/q0Xl2McbteimL6QIGi4I?p=preview